# how to declare a path as a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, path

How to declare a path as a variable to open a workbook?
I tried the code below, but it didn't try.
(In the cell "E1" there is the path "C:\Users....")

```
`Sub test()
Dim a as String
Set inp = Workbooks("input_dados".xlsx)
a = inp.Sheets("input").Range("E1").Value
Workbooks.Open(a)
End sub`
```

Comment: What is the value of `a`?

Comment: In the cell "E1" there is the path "C:\Users...."

Comment: With or without quotes?

Comment: `Set inp = Workbooks("input_dados.xlsx")` the extension is part of the name in this case. Also, the cell E1 should not have quotes for better, easier use.